# How to select a number of logins by a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I would like to select all login events and also the number of logins under one specific IP address by a MySQL query.

The Query that I have come up with is as follows. But I am afraid I have been missing something.
Hopefully one can see my mistake.

```
SELECT `pp_loginevent`.`loginevent_user`,   
       `pp_loginevent`.`loginevent_creationdate`, 
       `pp_loginevent`.`loginevent_ip`, 
       `pp_user`.`user_id`, 
       `pp_user`.`user_name`, 
       `pp_user`.`user_rights`, 
       `pp_user`.`user_active`, 
       `pp_license`.`license_name` 

   (SELECT COUNT(1) 
   FROM `pp_loginevent` 
   WHERE `loginevent_ip` = `pp_loginevent`.`loginevent_ip`
   ) AS `pp_loginevent`.`number_of_logins`

FROM `pp_loginevent`
    LEFT JOIN `pp_user` 
        ON `pp_loginevent`.`loginevent_user` = `pp_user`.`user_id
    LEFT JOIN `pp_license` 
        ON `pp_loginevent`.`loginevent_license` = `pp_license`.`license_id`

WHERE `loginevent_creationdate` LIKE '2019-%' 
       AND `user_rights` <= '6' 
GROUP BY `loginevent_ip` 
ORDER BY `loginevent_creationdate` DESC
```

What I am trying to do is to fetch the "column" `number_of_logins` and that should contain the number of logins made from a specific IP address.

Comment: I suspect that there are several errors in this query. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can't see anything wrong here:

```
`pp_license`.`license_name` 

(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `pp_loginevent` WHERE `loginevent_ip` = `pp_loginevent`.`loginevent_ip`) AS `pp_loginevent`.`number_of_logins`
```

?

While this won't resolve all the problems with this query, I think writing the query out this way makes one error very obvious:

```
SELECT e.loginevent_user
     , e.loginevent_creationdate
     , e.loginevent_ip
     , u.user_id
     , u.user_name
     , u.user_rights
     , u.user_active
     , l.license_name 
       (SELECT COUNT(1) 
          FROM pp_loginevent 
         WHERE loginevent_ip = pp_loginevent.loginevent_ip) pp_loginevent.number_of_logins

  FROM pp_loginevent e
  JOIN pp_user u
    ON u.user_id = e.loginevent_user 
  LEFT 
  JOIN pp_license l
    ON l.license_id = e.loginevent_license 
 WHERE e.loginevent_creationdate >= '2019-01-01' 
   AND e.loginevent_creationdate < '2020-01-01' 
   AND user_rights <= 6 
 GROUP 
    BY loginevent_ip 
 ORDER 
    BY loginevent_creationdate DESC
```

In truth, as well as this syntax error, I suspect that there are other, logical, errors in this query.

Accordingly, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Because I am pretty much blue as **** regarding MySQL queries.
So nope I do not see the syntax error. Whilst I know there is one.

Comment: @Alex What do you mean by "blue"?